# Create security rules out of CSV data

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I have the following data which is provided as extra vars.

```
TCP,22,22,10.10.10.10/0
TCP,8080,8080,0.0.0.0/0
```

So, as:

```bash
--extra-vars 'rules="TCP,22,22,10.10.10.10/0\nTCP,8080,8080,0.0.0.0/0"'
```

How can I create multiple `rules` block using Jinja based on the above CSV data?

Update: I need to have one static rule and rest using dynamic rule if the variable rules is supplied. If the rules extra vars isn't supplied then I want only the static rule to be present.

```yaml
- name: create ec2 security group
  # create a security group for the vpc
  amazon.aws.ec2_group:
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc_id }}"
    region: "{{ cloud_region }}"
    state: "present"
    name: "testing_sg_ansible"
    description: "testing_sg_ansible"
    tags:
      Name: "testing_sg_ansible"
    rules:
    - proto: tcp          # Static rule
      from_port: 8085
      to_port: 8085
      cidr_ip: "10.10.10.0/24"
    - proto: TCP          # Dynamic rules using extra vars
      from_port: 22
      to_port: 22
      cidr_ip: 10.10.10.10/0
    - proto: TCP
      from_port: 8080
      to_port: 8080
      cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could achieve this is by using JMESPath capabilities and a [multiselect hash](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#filters-and-multiselect-hashes).

```yaml
- name: create ec2 security group for the vpc
  amazon.aws.ec2_group:
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc_id }}"
    region: "{{ cloud_region }}"
    state: "present"
    name: "testing_sg_ansible"
    description: "testing_sg_ansible"
    tags:
      Name: "testing_sg_ansible"
    rules: >-   
      {{
        rules.splitlines()
        | map('split', ',')
        | json_query("[*].{
          proto: [0],
          from_port: [1],
          to_port: [2],
          cidr_ip: [3]
        }")
      }}
```

A playbook, run with the extra variables, this way:

```bash
ansible-playbook play.yml \
  --extra-vars 'rules="TCP,22,22,10.10.10.10/0\nTCP,8080,8080,0.0.0.0/0"'
```

Would create a `rules` parameter looking like your expected result:

```yaml
rules:
- cidr_ip: 10.10.10.10/0
  from_port: '22'
  proto: TCP
  to_port: '22'
- cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
  from_port: '8080'
  proto: TCP
  to_port: '8080'
```

---

As an example, given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg:
      rules: >-
        {{
          rules.splitlines()
          | map('split', ',')
          | json_query("[*].{
            proto: [0],
            from_port: [1],
            to_port: [2],
            cidr_ip: [3]
          }")
        }}
```

Run with:

```bash
ansible-playbook play.yml \
  --extra-vars 'rules="TCP,22,22,10.10.10.10/0\nTCP,8080,8080,0.0.0.0/0"'
```

Would yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
    rules:
    - cidr_ip: 10.10.10.10/0
      from_port: '22'
      proto: TCP
      to_port: '22'
    - cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
      from_port: '8080'
      proto: TCP
      to_port: '8080'
```

Comment: I've updated the question. Your code works but I need to have a static rule in between and the dynamic rule like your code should only run if the  `rules=` variable is present.

Comment: `when: rules is defined` condition might work but if the `rules` is not defined I need a static rule.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. `purge_rules: no` needs to be set otherwise dynamic rule will be overwritten.

```
 - name: create ec2 security group
    # create a security group for the vpc
    amazon.aws.ec2_group:
      vpc_id: "{{ vpc_id }}"
      region: "{{ cloud_region }}"
      state: "present"
      name: "{{ sg_name }}"
      description: "Security Group {{ sg_name }}"
      tags:
        Name: "{{ sg_name }}"
      rules: >-                       # Dynamic rule
        {{
          rules.splitlines()
          | map('split', ',')
          | json_query("[*].{
            proto: [0],
            from_port: [1],
            to_port: [2],
            cidr_ip: [3]
          }")
        }}
    when: rules is defined
    register: security_group_results


  - name: update Ec2 security group
    # update security group for the vpc
    amazon.aws.ec2_group:
      vpc_id: "{{ vpc_id }}"
      region: "{{ cloud_region }}"
      state: "present"
      name: "{{ sg_name }}"
      description: "Security Group {[ sg_name }}"
      tags:
        Name: "{{ sg_name }}"
      purge_rules: no             # This is important so it doesn't overwrite above rule.
      rules:                      # Static rule
      - proto: tcp
        from_port: 8086
        to_port: 8086
        cidr_ip: "10.10.10.0/24"
```